# For which sets $A$ do we have $A\subseteq \lim(F_A)$?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, convergence-divergence

Let $(X, \mathcal O)$ be a topological space. Given a proper filter $F$
let: $$\lim(F) := \{x\in X : F\to x\}$$ (of course: $F\to x$ means $F$ refines the neighborhood filter of $x$)

and given a set $A\subseteq X$, let $F_A$ the filter generated by $\{A\}$, which is $F_A = \{B\subseteq X : A\subseteq B\}$ and proper if and only, if $A\neq \varnothing$.

> For what sets $\varnothing \neq A\subseteq X$ do we have $A\subseteq \lim(F_A)$ besides $A=\{x\}$ for $x\in X$?

Are there well-known properties of $X$ that affect this property in some important way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A ⊆ \operatorname{lim}(F_A)$ if and only if every neighborhood of every member of $A$ contains whole $A$, which happens if and only if $A$ is an indiscrete subspace of $X$. So in $T_0$ spaces this happens only if $A = \{x\}$ for some $x ∈ X$.